# Change default color scheme in twentyfifteen child theme?

Tags: functions, child-theme, theme-customizer

I read the [previous ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193782/how-can-you-change-default-color-scheme-in-a-twenty-fifteen-child-theme) about this. And tried renaming my scheme to "default" and it didn't work.

I am implementing the child theme on 50+ blogs on a network and I would like to just click "Activate" rather than also choose the color scheme. Any help would be great. This is what I have in my child theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter('twentyfifteen_color_schemes', 'my_custom_color_schemes');
function my_custom_color_schemes( $schemes ) {
    $schemes['custom'] = array(
        'label'  => __( 'My Custom Colors', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'colors' => array(
            '#f8f7f4',
            '#002244',
            '#f8f7f4',
            '#585552',
            '#ffffff',
            '#f8f7f4',
        ),
    );
    return $schemes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'default' should work.  Did you try calling the colors and seeing if your filter is working?

If it's not you could try adding a higher priority to your filter

```
add_filter( 'twentyfifteen_color_schemes', 'my_custom_color_schemes', 99 );
function my_custom_color_schemes( $schemes ) {
    $schemes['default'] = array(
        'label'  => __( 'my new default color', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'colors' => array(
            '#f8f7f4',
            '#002244',
            '#f8f7f4',
            '#585552',
            '#ffffff',
            '#f8f7f4',
        ),
    );
    return $schemes;
}
```

Comment: I did both of those, independently and together. When I rename and add a higher priority, it replaces the default scheme with My Custom Colors, and that's at the top of the drop down list. But the new colors aren't applied.

Without the ['default'] or priority, no other changes, my color scheme is at the end of the list, and if selected through the customizer, functions properly.

Comment: when you had the array as custom, did it show up on the backend as a color scheme choice?

Comment: Yes - it shows up at the bottom of the list, and works as expected.

Comment: i just added this to the functions.php in twentyfifteen and loaded up the theme.  It overwrote "default" with "my new default color" and was selected.  All colors were changed.

Comment: Very strange. I’ll have to spin up a clone and see what’s up. Thanks for digging into it!

Comment: keep me updated!